# htaccess cache based on version number in meta tag

Tags: .htaccess, caching

Is it possible to cache the website files (images, html, css, js) based on your version number?

In more detail: 
I would like to have a version number in my header of the html files. So when someone visit my website the files will be cached. But when he visit my website again it should check the version numbers to registrate if there are new files (images, css, js, html ect) to download. If so it should do that. If not it can used the old cache files.

```
Something like this:
-------------------------------
<meta name="version" content="1">

# if version number is higher than client number download new files or else use cache files

<filesMatch "\.(xml|txt|html|js|css|jpg|png)$">
  ExpiresDefault A7200
  Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not from a `<meta>` tag, no. But you could just tag the version you want on to the end of the request for the resource, and make use of it appropriately. So do things like:

```
<img src="/images/image.jpg?v=1" alt="">
```

Or you could set a cookie with the version you want and check for that.

This all seems a very strange thing to be doing though. Perhaps if you take a step back and explain what problem you're trying to solve, there might be a better solution.